# Adding a Policy-based Authorization skips JWT bearer token authentication check?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I have a REST API service that implements JWT bearer token based authentication obtained from Azure AD.

```
        // add support for custom Authorization policies
        services
            .AddAuthorization(authoptions =>
            {
                authoptions.AddPolicy("MemberOfUsersADGroup", policy =>
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new IsMemberOfUsersADGroup())
                    );
            })
            .AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, IsMemberOfUsersADGroupAuthHandler>();

        // add support for this service to recieve OAUTH2 JWT bearer tokens
        services
            .AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
            {
                authOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                // token validation (REQUIRED)
                options.Audience = "AUDIENCE GUID";
                options.Authority = String.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANTGUID]/");
            });
```

And here's how the policy authorizaton handler is implemented. IT returns **success unconditionally**.

```
    public class IsMemberOfSenseiUsersADGroup : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

    public class IsMemberOfUsersADGroupAuthHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsMemberOfUsersADGroup>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsMemberOfUsersADGroup requirement)
    {
     // unconditional success for now
     context.Succeed(requirement);
     return Task.CompletedTask; 
    }
}
```

**CASE 1**
If I decorate my controller like this, and call without a bearer token, then I get a 401 as expected.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/dostuff")]
public class DoStuffController : Controller
{
```

**CASE 2**
HOWEVER, if I decorate my controller with the Policy, and call without a bearer token, ***then the REST API call passes fine and doesnt require a bearer token at all!!!*** I see the call enter into the AuthHandler HandleRequirementAsync() and then it succeeds, even tho bearer tokens were not passed in.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MemberOfUsersADGroup")]
[Route("api/dostuff")]
public class DoStuffController : Controller
{
```

I am unable to explain this behavior at all. I am glad I caught this in my testing because I assumed the policy check is additive (as indicated by "AddPolicy" call), but it seems to replace the entire validation chain incl. the one done by JWT bearer middleware in CASE 1.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it related to the ordering of the Add*** calls made in ConfigureServices() How do I make sure the JWT bearer token validation occurs no matter if the policy authhandler checks pass or not?

Comment: Looks like right before I perform .AddPolicy() and add in my custom policy, authoptions.DefaultPolicy.Requirements has 1 policy already present of type {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement}. However, it is removed as soon as .AddPolicy is called. Which very likely explains what is happening here. Still investigating more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the expected behavior.

If you want your authorization policy to reject unauthenticated requests, simply call [`builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireauthenticateduser?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thanks! Yes, I just found that one myself as well (from github sources). So I was also missing a TokenValidationParameters setting which also works - even without the RequireAuthenticatedUser() - of course, because TokenValidationParameters checks for existence of Issuer/Audience/etc. which means Bearer token cannot be empty which means the user has to be authenticated. I am adding both mechanisms for 'extra safety' :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a same problem. My workaround was that I put controller under default `[Authorize]` attribute and then every action has it's own policy `[Authorize(Policy = "MemberOfUsersADGroup")]`. To me it wasn't such a big deal because I had only one controller which action's was under the same policy. RequireAuthenticatedUser and similar wasn't necessary.